# Postgre floor changes values postgresql

Tags: postgresql, math, rounding, floor

I have the following query

```
with debug as (
    select kode_toko_dbo 
    , kode_toko_final
    , nama_toko_final
    , concat (point_category,' - ',point) poin_kategori
    , point
    , sum(total_do_qty) total_do_qty
    , sum(case when upper(replace(item_name,' ','')) ~ upper('^.*Classic.*(6|8)') then floor(total_do_qty::numeric /10)
        when upper(kategori_name_l1) = 'RB FASCIA' then (floor(total_do_qty::numeric /10))
        when upper(replace(item_name,' ','')) ~  upper('^.*Classic.*(3|4)\.5') then floor(total_do_qty::numeric /10)
        else 0 end) reward_toko
    from outputnya 
    group by 1,2,3,4,5
    --order by reward_toko desc 
    )
    select kode_toko_dbo 
    , kode_toko_final 
    , nama_toko_final 
    , poin_kategori
    , point
    , total_do_qty
    , reward_toko   
    from debug
    where kode_toko_final  in ('2012000044','2012000044')
    order by reward_toko desc
```

it gives the the following results:
[image]

When we devide `8417` with `10`, it returns `841` which is correct.

When we divide `2950` with `10`, it returns `293` which is wrong. It shud returns `295`.

How do i resolve this?

when i tried the following query:

```
select 2950
, floor(2950::numeric / 10)
, floor(2950::numeric / 10) * 4 
limit 5
```

it gives me the correct results.

[image]

How do i resolve this?

Comment: So don't use the floor (or round) inside the sum, do it outside the sum of the values

Comment: and why is that @nacho?

Comment: In that `CASE` expression there is an `ELSE` branch that returns 0. That may well account for the difference. I cannot tell if that is the problem, because I don't know your data. Consider creating a minimal self-contained reproducer for the problem, that will allow up to reproduce and analyze your problem.

Comment: I followed @nacho recommendations and it worked. I just don't know why it worked. Yes, will do. Thanks Laurenz Albe

Comment: Because if you have decimal numbers like 2.2 & 2.9, the sum is 5.1, if you do the floor, you get 5. But if first, you do the floor, you get 2 & 2, and the sum is 4